# View all shared folders a member has access to

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I've been looking at the [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shared-folders) and [Dropbox for Business API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/business/docs#members-get-info) and I was trying to see if it would be possible to create a list of all the members and what shared folders they have access to.

I have found a [project by Dropbox](https://sfmdemo.herokuapp.com/) ([Github Source](https://github.com/dropbox/sfmdemo)) that lists all the shared folders and which people have access to them. I essentially want to do the opposite, list the users and what folders they have.

I have read through all the API (Core and Business) docs but can't seem to find a way to do it, unless I'm missing something. I also read about a preview of the [new API](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/04/a-preview-of-the-new-dropbox-api-v2/), but again I don't think that is what I want.

Does anyone know if this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, you just need to call [`/shared_folders`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shared-folders) for each member of the team.

(You can list the members of the team via [`/team/members/list`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/business/docs#members-list).)

Comment: I can't do it that way as I am only authenticated using my Dropbox account (as I have access to every folder and everyone else doesn't). So using /shared_folders I can only view the members of a specific folder or members of all folders

Comment: @Harry12345 So you're **not** using the Dropbox for Business API? If you can see the membership of all the shared folders, aren't you done already?

Comment: Yeah I've done it now. I didn't need to use the Business API in the end. I think I was just getting the two confused. Anyway I've sorted it now